# How do I convert the value for data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Please note that this question is not about type conversion or formatting in data binding.

I have a small application which draws a rectangle on a canvas. User have a UI to enter the rectangle's width. This value is stored in user.config. The problem is that end-user wants to enter the width in inch or millimeter but in WPF the rectangle's width is measured in display independent pixels (DIP). Therefore, I have to multiply the user's input by 96 if he uses inch or by 3.84 if he uses millimeter. How do I achieve this and still take advantage of data binding.

This is my current XAML for data binding Rectangle's width

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvasPanel" >
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="{Binding Default.Width, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Settings}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

And this is my current XAML for data binding user's input

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Default.Width, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Settings}}"/>
```

And of course, I don't forget to declare a static resource in App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="DefectSim.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:DefectSim.Properties"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
   <Application.Resources>
        <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings"/>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a binding [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will handle the requirement of extracting information from the user config and provide the right value.

If needed use a [multibinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) binding to allow for more values to be passed into the converter.

Comment: Converter is enough for solving my problem. However, can you give me a bit of details when I should use multibinding instead of simple converter?

Comment: @LxL Use the multibinding say in the case where you need to send a user selection, say from the Xaml which might not be available to the converter. I had such a need where the converter would pivot off of such a selection and return other values.